# WEKA: Simple Logistic prediction understanding

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, weka, logistic-regression

I am confused by the prediction given by WEKA for the trained model:

### ARFF schema

```
@RELATION sportsArffWithEmpty

@ATTRIBUTE "annotation" {"DIFFERENT","SAME"}
@ATTRIBUTE "item_name" REAL
@ATTRIBUTE "brand" {"EMPTY","IGNORE","MATCHED","NOT_MATCH"}
@ATTRIBUTE "manufacturer" {"EMPTY","IGNORE","MATCHED","NOT_MATCH"}
@ATTRIBUTE "part_number" {"EMPTY","IGNORE","MATCHED","NOT_MATCH"}
@ATTRIBUTE "color" {"EMPTY","IGNORE","MATCHED","NOT_MATCH"}
@ATTRIBUTE "size" {"EMPTY","IGNORE","MATCHED","NOT_MATCH"}
```

### Trained model

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:       weka.classifiers.functions.SimpleLogistic -I 0 -M 500 -H 50 -W 0.0
Relation:     sportsArffWithEmpty
Instances:    263
Attributes:   7
              annotation
              item_name
              brand
              manufacturer
              part_number
              color
              size
Test mode:    user supplied test set:  size unknown (reading incrementally)

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===
SimpleLogistic:

Class 0 :
-2 +
[color=MATCHED] * 1.15 +
[size=IGNORE] * 1.03 +
[size=MATCHED] * -0.56 +
[size=NOT_MATCH] * 1.12

Class 1 :
2    +
[color=MATCHED] * -1.15 +
[size=IGNORE] * -1.03 +
[size=MATCHED] * 0.56 +
[size=NOT_MATCH] * -1.12
```

### Instance

```
@DATA
"SAME","0.632","MATCHED","NOT_MATCH","MATCHED","MATCHED","MATCHED"
```

Prediction given by WEKA

```
=== Predictions on test set ===

inst#,actual,predicted,error,prediction
1,2:SAME,2:SAME,,0.945
```

### Personal calculation

```
The coefficient should be
-2    +
[color=MATCHED] * -1.15 +
[size=IGNORE] * -1.03 +
[size=MATCHED] * 0.56 +
[size=NOT_MATCH] * -1.12
= -2+ 1*-1.15 + 0*-1.03 + 1* 0.56 + 0* -1.12
= 1.41
```

So the output should be `1/(1+ e^-1.41)` = `0.8037`, but the prediction given by WEKA is `0.945`

1. what is the problem here?
2. Why the trained model does not take `item_name`, `brand` etc. into consideration?

---

### Answer to question 1

According to [WEKA forum](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Calculating-Class-Probabilities-Simple-Logistic-td29352.html),

```
SimpleLogistic uses what’s called a symmetric model by Friedman et al.
(2000), “Additive logistic regression: A statistical view of boosting”, 
Annals of Statistics 28(2). See page 354 in that paper.
```

So the answer of quesion 1 is calculated as `e^1.41/(e^1.41 + e^ (-1.41)) = 0.94`

### Quesion

Why the trained model does not take `item_name`, `brand` etc. into consideration, is it related to my dataset's bias?